# Bias Variance decomposition derivation question/proof (from Wikipedia)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, mathematical-statistics

I have a question on [this derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Derivation) of the bias-variance decomposition.  At some point they have this part of the expression --> $\mathbf{E}[2y\hat{f}]$ and they say that $\epsilon$ and $\hat{f}$ are independent and so they break it as $2f\mathbf{E}[\hat{f}]$ (I also don't understand why $\epsilon$ and $\hat{f}$ are independent).

My question is this: can we say that $$\mathbf{E}[2y\hat{f}] = 2f\mathbf{E}[\hat{f}]$$ 
if we knew that $y_i$ are independent outcomes of $Y$ in $y_i = f(x_i)+\epsilon$  and also have shown that $\mathbf{E}[Y]=f$, or, is it absolutely vital to say that both $\epsilon$ and $\hat{f}$ are independent?

Thank you!

Comment: I think $\hat{f}$ and $\epsilon$ are $assumed$ to be independent. If that is true, and $y$ is just a function of the latter, then the expectation result holds. I am not sure what you mean by ys independent outcomes of Y.

Comment: I just edited my original post, is it clearer the part "ys independent outcomes of Y" ?

Comment: Intuitively, $\epsilon$ is the irreducible error due to e.g. measurement errors, which is independent from the model estimates $\hat f$. However, in practice, the level of noise in training data determines the data quality, which in turn impose huge impact on getting $\hat f$. This means the distribution of predictions somehow depends on the noise distribution. Looking forward to another answer on this.

Comment: When looking at bias-variance derivation in detail like you are, it helps to take care about what those expectations are with respect to. $E[\hat f]=E_D[\hat f]$ is a function of $x$ and is the expectation over training data sets. LIkewise $Var_D[\hat f]$. $E[y]=f$ and $E[\epsilon^2]=\sigma^2$ are wrt the target distribution, $y$. Then you want to average the whole result over the input/feature distribution $x$. Learning From Data at Caltech derives it with care.

Comment: For anyone interested: I had the same question and re-posted on [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693240/bias-variance-tradeoff-derivation?noredirect=1#comment9929739_4693240). A comment was made that I found pretty helpful!

Comment: If $\epsilon$ and $\hat{f}$ aren't independent, then $\hat{f}$ can be improved by removing the dependency.  Consider the following simple example:  when $\hat{f} = 1$, $\mathbb{E}\epsilon = 1$.  I can improve my model by setting $\hat{f} = 2$ whenever it would "normally" equal $1$.  So we do assume independence, but it's a reasonable assumption.